# SQL Server - Dynamic multi column pivot

Tags: sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

I have results like this, the `Annual` is dynamic and may have X amount of ranges

```
+-----------+---------+-----------+
| Annual    | Revenue | Completed |
+-----------+---------+-----------+
| 2020/2021 | 1000    | Yes       |
+-----------+---------+-----------+
| 2021/2022 | 2000    | Yes       |
+-----------+---------+-----------+
| 2022/2023 | 2500    | No        |
+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

I'm looking to have results like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Annual    | 2020/2021 | 2021/2022 | 2022/2023 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Revenue   | 1000      | 2000      | 2500      |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Completed | Yes       | Yes       | No        |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Here's what I got so far, I can execute on my local but can't seem to get it to execute on sqlfiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a4c61/4

I've looked at examples all over stackoverflow but couldn't seem to find an exact case like mine.

Please help if you can, thank you!

```
Sql version: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   May 15 2020 00:47:08
```

Comment: You can create dynamic sql string to create a temp table and insert the values by loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dynamic data recommendations**

You can get count and use `StringBuilder` to generate `strSQL`.

```
        StringBuilder strSQL = new StringBuilder();
        int DataAmount = 3;// a,b,c,d,e
        Dictionary<int, string> dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        dic.Add(0 ,"a");
        dic.Add(1, "b");
        dic.Add(2, "c");
        strSQL.Append("select ");
        strSQL.Append(" isnull(a.Column2,b.Column2) Column0,isnull(a.Column1,0) Column1 ");
        //dic.Count > 2
        for (int i = 1; i < dic.Count; i++)
        {
            strSQL.Append(",isnull("+dic[i]+".Column1,0) Column"+i+" ");
        }
        strSQL.Append(" from (SELECT ID,Column1,Column2 FROM [dbo].[20200618] UNPIVOT(Column1 for Column2 in ([Annual],[Revenue],[Completed]))b where ID=1) a ");

        for (int j = 1; j < dic.Count; j++)
        {
            strSQL.Append("FULL JOIN (SELECT ID, Column1, Column2 FROM[dbo].[20200618] UNPIVOT(Column1 for Column2 in ([Annual],[Revenue],[Completed])) " + dic[j] + "  where ID = " + (j+1)+ ") " + dic[j] + " on a.Column2 = " + dic[j]+".Column2 ");
        }
       // SqlHelper.ExcuteNoQuery(strSQL.ToString());
```

**SQL Query Part**

Data in my azure sqlserver.

[image]

When run `SELECT *FROM [dbo].[20200618]` .

[image]

Run `SELECT ID,Column1,Column2 FROM [dbo].[20200618] UNPIVOT(Column1 for Column2 in ([Annual],[Revenue],[Completed]))b where ID=2`.

[image]

Finally, run the code.

```
select isnull(a.Column2,b.Column2) Column0,isnull(a.Column1,0) Column1,isnull(b.Column1,0) Column2,isnull(c.Column1,0) Column3 from (SELECT ID,Column1,Column2 FROM [dbo].[20200618] UNPIVOT(Column1 for Column2 in ([Annual],[Revenue],[Completed]))b where ID=1) a FULL JOIN (SELECT ID,Column1,Column2 FROM [dbo].[20200618] UNPIVOT(Column1 for Column2 in ([Annual],[Revenue],[Completed]))b where ID=2) b on a.Column2=b.Column2 FULL JOIN (SELECT ID,Column1,Column2 FROM [dbo].[20200618] UNPIVOT(Column1 for Column2 in ([Annual],[Revenue],[Completed]))b where ID=3) c on a.Column2=c.Column2
```

[image]